# ImageButton inside absolute div is not responsive

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, imagebutton

Little problem has occurred in my code and I don't know why... Let's begin:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="top img-responsive" ImageUrl="~/images/site/top.jpg" />
            <div class="pl">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" PostBackUrl="http://example.com/" ImageUrl="~/images/site/przycisk pl.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="d">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" PostBackUrl="http://example.com/de/" ImageUrl="~/images/site/przycisk d.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="uk">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" PostBackUrl="http://example.com/" ImageUrl="~/images/site/przycisk uk.png" />
            </div>
</div>
```

Those ImageButtons should be responsive, but when I scale website the Image is responsive and scalling, but ImageButtons stay the same all the time.

CSS:

```
.pl
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.125%;
    left: 70%;
    z-index: 4;
    display: inline-block;
}

.d
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.125%;
    left: 75%;
    z-index: 4;
}

.uk
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.125%;
    left: 80%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Any ideas, why are they not scalling together with Image?

Comment: add your code  js fiddle

Comment: inspect the button after it's rendered on the page, because these are asp elements and created by the server it's very likely that what's being created and actually added to the page isn't what you expected